# Custom IValueConverter inheriting from DependencyObject

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter, dependencyobject

I wanted to experiment with being able to have a converter whose arguments can be bound with the current data context. Can anyone tell me why when reaching the Convert() function, the Source property is always null?

```
namespace WpfApplication32
{
    public class ConverterTest : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(DependencyObject), typeof(ConverterTest));

        public DependencyObject Source
        {
            get { return (DependencyObject)this.GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Value = 7;

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public float Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}




<Window x:Class="WpfApplication32.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication32">

    <Slider>
        <Slider.Value>
            <Binding Path="Value">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:ConverterTest Source="{Binding}"/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Slider.Value>
    </Slider>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to make your Converter inherit from **Freezable** instead ([Hillberg Freezable trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/21/model-see_2c00_-model-do.aspx)). Then you can even define your Converter in your Resources and reference it in your binding as an attribute instead of an extra child element.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work, but I dont know why. Why is it that the original code didnt work? I feel Im missing knowledge which is required before the workaround you linked to makes sense.

Comment: Basically, for some reason Freezable inherits the DataContext while most resources and things that are not part of the visual tree do not. They are special. Here.. this explains more http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/05/22/leveraging-freezables-to-provide-an-inheritance-context-for-bindings/

Comment: This totally got me, it was pain